# Download GIt MACOS

Tags: git, github, download

I am using MacOS and Git does not automatically start the download on its website and redirects the downloading from SourceForge. I wanted to know if thats a trustable website to download Git for MacOS?

Comment: You can download git for MacOS from here: https://git-scm.com/download/mac
The files are hosted on SourceForge. This is a trusted source.

Comment: Yes, but it is not automatically getting downloaded from  git-scm.com/download/mac. So it says then for manual downloading, it redirects to Source Forge @Henridv

Comment: As I mentioned, this is a trusted source, so there is not an issue downloading the installation file from there.

Comment: okay thanks :) @Henridv